# When using conjunctions in a question to connect two sentences, should I add a comma before the conjunction?

Tags: grammar, british-english

When using conjunctions in a question to connect two sentences, should I add a comma before the conjunction?

For example,

> Why did you leave me to be like this *,and* disappear without a single trace?

Or,

> Why did you leave me to be like this *and* disappear without a single trace?

Answer (score 0):

> ([The Writing Center](https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/grammarpunct/coordconj/)) When a coordinating conjunction joins two independent clauses, a comma is used before the coordinating conjunction (unless the two independent clauses are very short).

This is no hard and fast rule; however, in the case of fairly long clauses a comma seems to be used without fail.

> (*Examples from CoGEL*)
>
> - He heard an explosion *and* he  therefore phoned the police.
> - Go by air, *and* save time.
> - Join the navy *and* see the world.
> - They are living in England, *or* they are spending a vacation there.
> - She felt ill, *and* my mother said nothing.
> - I spoke to him before the conference was over, but before he started work.
> - He tried hard, but he failed.
> - John plays the guitar, and his sister plays the piano.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I want to know how short the two independent clauses have to be to not have a comma before the their conjuction.

Comment: @Guest How short can be summed up by a SVO-, SVC-, SVA- structure in which the S, V, C, and A are short (one  word, ideally, or two), as in the first and third examples I showed (very short). However, sometimes, in those cases of very short clauses (second example) a comma can still be used. It probably wouldn't be considered a bad mistake to use a comma in the first and second examples.

Comment: Perhaps the archetypal _shortest version_ is what Julius Caesar uttered aeons back: _I came, I saw, I conquered._

Comment: @user405662 This is a sort of coordination but it involves no conjunctions, and in fact if we were to insert conjunctions we would use only one; "I came and I saw and I conquered." is not the usual syntax; "I came, I saw, and I conquered." would be how to write that (ellipsis of the first one). Not using this ellipsis is done as a rhetorical device. However, when more than two conjuncts are used, a comma is placed after the second conjunct according to certain principles that have nothing to do with the length of the clauses.